# Make a variable memorize a value, according with a boolean state of another variable

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to implement a "latch" function in Javascript that stores the value of a numeric variable 'x', (which count up constantly, automatically) depending on the state of a second variable 'y' (boolean type, user-interact)? Something like this:

```
x = // count up constantly,
x1 = store the x value when ->
y = is "false" (EVEN IF it becomes "true" again)
```

The problem is that when "y" returns to the "true" state, "x1" loses the stored value and becomes "undefined" again, and I need that value to do a math operation (subtraction) later. Does anyone know how to solve this (I´m very noob in Javascript)?

Here the code I reached until now:

```
    var x = // this value change constantly
      function latchON() {
          var x1;
       if (!y) {
           x1 = x;    
           return x1;
       }
      }

z = latchON() - x // this is operation  I need perform, but result "NaN", because x1 is "undefined" when y become "true"...
```

Sorry if I could not explain very well, and sorry for my bad English too (not my native language).

EDIT - Thanks to everyone who tried to help me. I finally managed to solve it, using cookies to store values (I wasted a week trying before I remembered it :( but later than never...), following some instructions on this page http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: Don't add corrections as comments, just edit the question. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you wanted to do, but how about this?

```
var x = // this value change constantly
var x1 = 0
function latchON() {
    if (!y) {
        x1 = x;     
    }
    return x1;
}
```

Comment: A little more explanation might help the OP. ;-)

Comment: here you define x1 outside the function, so its value will stay since last being changed.  in your version, x1 is a local variable with no initial value so you'd get NaN if y is true.

Comment: also from what you wrote, you always expected the function to return a value, so the return statement should be put outside the if block.